# How to limit the number of results in jQuery autocomplete?

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I have searched enough, but am not able to find the solution to this. Could you please help me out.

I have a table which has around 700 records, and I want the autocomplete to display not more than 5 records in the result. It should have a scroll bar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunetely there is no bulit in property to set max limit. You can use:

```
$("#autocmplt").autocomplete({
source: function(req, response) {
    var results = $.ui.autocomplete.filter(myarray, req.term);

    response(results.slice(0, 5));//for getting 5 results
   }
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vqwBP/502/)**

Comment: Hi, thanks. Can you please guide me as to where I should place this code. I am a total newbie, and code very rarely.

Comment: @DeepakBM: the place where you have set `autocomplete`.add source parameter like above example.

Comment: @MilindAnantwar .. what's req.term for ? Can u explain it

Comment: @RidoanSalehNasution: https://forum.jquery.com/topic/what-is-request-term